# Could not find or load main class package.ClassName

Tags: java, package

I have two packages and classes
First package

**D:\User\java\java_programs\mypackage\A.java**

```
package mypackage;
public class A
{
    public void msg(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello "+name);
    }
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("hello User");
    }
}
```

And There is another class B in **C:\package1\B.java**

```
package package1;
import mypackage.A;
public class B
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        A obj = new A();
        obj.msg("User");
    }
}
```

I compiled

`C:\package1>javac -cp d:\User\java\java_programs\ B.java`

And It created the class files for both **A.java** and **B.java**

But I cannot run my code

**I tried**

`java -cp d:\User\java\java_programs\ package1.B`

But Error

> Error: Could not find or load main class package1.B

Comment: You need to read up on how the Java classpath works, for package1 your root of the classpath would be `C;\`. If you add `C:\` to the -cp argument it will probably work like you expected.

Comment: you mean to run class b java -cp c;` package1.B @rsp It does not work. same error

Comment: I meant `java -cp C:\;D:\User\java\java_programs package1.B` (the backslash was not escaped in my previous comment)

Comment: It worked thanks. I need to include both classes in classpath with backslash  escaped. classpath of two different classes is seperated by semicolon. official oracle doc does not describe packages in different drives. @rsp

Comment: it is working without escaping backslash symbol. @rsp java-cp c:\;d:\User\java\java_programs package1.B

Comment: I think you should post it as an answer. @rsp

Comment: done (summarized the comments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up on how the Java classpath works, for package1 your root of the classpath would be `C:\`. If you add `C:\` to the -cp argument it will do what you need.

The command line becomes

```
java -cp C:\;D:\User\java\java_programs package1.B
```

The Java classpath consists of the root folders under which your package structures can be found. (Jar files contain the package folder structure starting from their root.)